# Plotting R objects within docker container

Tags: r, macos, docker

I am new to docker (working on OSX) and am trying to run R scripts within it and came across a hurdle when tried to create plots in a loop with docker. The code recurrently calls a script like that:

`pdf(plotname)
boxplot(X)
dev.off()`

The routine seems to work and does not produce any error message, but the plots are not created.

Any suggestions as to how to overcome this?

Original docker run

`#!/bin/bash`

`docker run -v`pwd`"/data":/data -ti jbms/fuzzycmeans $1`

$1 is the datafilename

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: This answer require further information to get the container working on OSX.*

---

Share your X11 display to the docker container:

```
docker run -it \
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
    -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY \
    # the rest of your docker run
```

So it is able to open graphics windows

Comment: I tried that and got this error message: "docker run" requires at least 1 argument(s).
See 'docker run --help'.

Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

Comment: docker run -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY 
[ ! -d "data" ] && echo "Copying sample data" && cp -rf sampleData data
docker run -v `pwd`"/data":/data -ti jbms/fuzzycmeans $1

Comment: [ ! -d "data" ].. and the second docker run are in different lines

Comment: My example shows what you have to add to your current `docker run` command. Do you follow me?

Comment: I do. Trying to figure out how accommodate the other things I need in the docker run.

Comment: Bear in mind that what you put after the image name (`jbms/fuzzycmeans`) is the command that runs inside the container. So add the -v and -e that I've provoded before that

Comment: ok. I guess that my problem is that I already have a -v `pwd`"/data":/data that I need to keep there because the code does other things in addition to the plot, which is the very last thing I do, and am not sure how to add your -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix without conflicting.

Comment: You can add as many -v as you need. If you post your original `docker run` command, I'll adapt it

Comment: `docker run -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY -v $(pwd)/data:/data -ti jbms/fuzzycmeans $1`

Comment: Now I got this error message: Unable to find image 'jbms/fuzzycmean:latest' locally

Comment: I got rid of the error message, but it is still not creating the plots. Sorry to bother you so much with this.

Comment: I will search for an example

Comment: I just realized that you are in OSX... Doh..! You need to install something to get what your are trying done. I'm preparing an example

Comment: Thank you Robert!

Comment: @JuliannoSambatti, I'm so sorry. I've been investigating and I've found difficult to connect a docker container in OSX to X11. I think that this is possible with this: https://www.xquartz.org/index.html (because OSX has not X11 native), and with some docker tricks.